# Calculate proportions of survey responses that picked one option also picking each of the other options in a multiple choice question

Tags: r, dplyr, data-mining

I am processing responses from a survey where a respondent can choose from a list of barriers that affect why they might or might not publish their writings (`dput()` of the data is appended at the end of this post). It's basically a multiple choice question. The data is in the form of a `tibble` data frame, let's call it `data`, like this:

```
> data
# A tibble: 927 × 2
   Response_ID barriers                       
         <int> <fct>                          
 1           1 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
 2           1 "Not how things are done"      
 3           2 "Insufficient \"impact\""      
 4           2 "Not how things are done"      
 5           2 "Don't know where to publish"  
 6           3 "Don't know how to write it up"
 7           4 "Not how things are done"      
 8           5 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
 9           6 "Don't know where to publish"  
10           7 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      
11           8 "Insufficient \"impact\""      
12           8 "Don't know how to write it up"
13           8 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
14           8 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      
15           8 "Not how things are done"      
16           9 "No benefit to career"         
17           9 "Don't expect useful feedback" 
18          10 "No benefit to career"         
19          10 "Don't expect useful feedback" 
20          11 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
21          12 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
22          12 "Insufficient \"impact\""      
23          12 "Not how things are done"      
24          12 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      
25          13 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
26          14 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
27          15 "Don't know how to write it up"
28          16 "Fear of being \"scooped\""    
29          16 "Don't expect useful feedback" 
30          17 "Don't expect useful feedback" 
# … with 897 more rows
```

There are 406 unique `Response_ID`s which correspond to the 406 people who responded to the survey. Each respondent can choose from *any number* of barriers from the following:

```
> unique(data$barriers)
[1] Fear of being "scooped"       Not how things are done       Insufficient "impact"        
[4] Don't know where to publish   Don't know how to write it up Fear of being "wrong"        
[7] No benefit to career          Don't expect useful feedback 
8 Levels: Fear of being "wrong" Don't expect useful feedback ... Fear of being "scooped"
```

As you can see from the data, respondent number one (`Response_ID == 1`) chose two barriers: `Fear of being "scooped"` and `Not how things are done`.

I would like to calculate the proportions of respondents who chose one of these barriers that also each of the other seven barriers.

For example, for every respondent (out of 406) that chose `Don't know where to publish` in their response, what are the *proportions* of them also choosing each of the other seven barriers? A possible result would be that of the 40 people who picked `Don't know where to publish`, 20% also chose `Not how things are done`, 30% also chose `Insufficient "impact"`, and so on.

Also note that, for example, the proportions of those who chose `Insufficient "impact"` and also picked `Don't know where to publish` might not be the same as the other way around.

Eventually, I want to plot the results using `ggplot2` in a `geom_tile`-based "heatmap" where the axes are the eight barriers, and each tile in the heatmap is along a color gradient representing the proportion of those who chose one barrier that also chose another barrier.

How do I perform these calculations? Thank you in advance.

(a tidyverse solution is strongly preferred but not strictly required)

P.S. The `dput()` from my data is as follows:

```
structure(list(Response_ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 
62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 
67L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 
89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
104L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 
113L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 
117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 121L, 
122L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 
127L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 133L, 
133L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 
138L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 
142L, 142L, 142L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 145L, 
145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 
156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 163L, 164L, 
164L, 164L, 165L, 165L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 
173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 178L, 
178L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 
189L, 189L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 
191L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 
194L, 194L, 194L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 196L, 
196L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 199L, 199L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 201L, 201L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 205L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 207L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 209L, 
210L, 210L, 211L, 211L, 212L, 212L, 212L, 213L, 213L, 213L, 214L, 
214L, 214L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 216L, 217L, 217L, 218L, 218L, 218L, 
219L, 219L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 224L, 
224L, 225L, 225L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 229L, 230L, 
230L, 231L, 231L, 231L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 240L, 241L, 
242L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 247L, 
247L, 247L, 247L, 248L, 248L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 251L, 
252L, 252L, 252L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 254L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 
258L, 259L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 263L, 264L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 269L, 269L, 
269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 273L, 274L, 274L, 275L, 275L, 276L, 
276L, 276L, 277L, 277L, 278L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 280L, 281L, 281L, 
282L, 282L, 282L, 282L, 283L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 
286L, 286L, 286L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 
290L, 291L, 291L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 293L, 294L, 294L, 294L, 294L, 
295L, 296L, 296L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 298L, 298L, 298L, 299L, 
300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 303L, 303L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 305L, 306L, 
306L, 306L, 306L, 306L, 306L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 310L, 
311L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 317L, 318L, 
318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 322L, 322L, 322L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 
324L, 325L, 326L, 326L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 329L, 
329L, 330L, 330L, 331L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 333L, 334L, 334L, 335L, 
335L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 339L, 339L, 340L, 340L, 340L, 
341L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 342L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 346L, 
347L, 347L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 350L, 351L, 351L, 352L, 
352L, 352L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 
359L, 360L, 360L, 361L, 361L, 361L, 361L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 
362L, 362L, 363L, 363L, 364L, 364L, 365L, 365L, 365L, 366L, 366L, 
367L, 367L, 367L, 368L, 368L, 369L, 369L, 369L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 
371L, 371L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 
379L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 380L, 380L, 380L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 
383L, 383L, 384L, 384L, 384L, 384L, 385L, 385L, 386L, 386L, 386L, 
387L, 387L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 390L, 390L, 
390L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 395L, 
396L, 396L, 396L, 397L, 397L, 397L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
399L, 399L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 
405L, 405L, 406L), barriers = structure(c(8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 
8L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
3L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 
3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 
7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
8L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
8L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 
8L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 
7L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 
3L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Fear of being \"wrong\"", 
"Don't expect useful feedback", "Don't know how to write it up", 
"Not how things are done", "Insufficient \"impact\"", "No benefit to career", 
"Don't know where to publish", "Fear of being \"scooped\""), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-927L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're doing a basic ***association rules*** mining. There have been a variety of algorithms and packages (e.g. `{arules}`) devoted to this field. Now that you're interested in one-to-one rules, we can attempt to implement the mining with a `{dplyr}` workflow:

```r
library(dplyr)

association <- df %>%
  full_join(df, by = "Response_ID", multiple = "all", suffix = c(".pre", ".post")) %>%
  count(barriers.pre, barriers.post) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / max(n), .by = barriers.pre)

# # A tibble: 64 × 4
#    barriers.pre                   barriers.post                       n   prop
#    <fct>                          <fct>                           <int>  <dbl>
#  1 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Fear of being \"wrong\""          48 1     
#  2 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Don't expect useful feedback"      6 0.125 
#  3 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Don't know how to write it up"    12 0.25  
#  4 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Not how things are done"          12 0.25  
#  5 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Insufficient \"impact\""          20 0.417 
#  6 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "No benefit to career"             11 0.229 
#  7 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Don't know where to publish"      10 0.208 
#  8 "Fear of being \"wrong\""      "Fear of being \"scooped\""        19 0.396   
# … with 56 more rows
```

###### Heatmap

```r
library(ggplot2)

association %>%
  mutate(prop = replace(prop, barriers.pre == barriers.post, NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(barriers.post, barriers.pre, fill = prop)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)(prop))) +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = 8, direction = 1) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! I think this is indeed what I'm looking for. Quick question: How do I see which half of the heatmap is for which *direction* of association? E.g. if I look at the top right tile, does that mean 40% of those who chose "Fear of being wrong" also chose "Fear of being scooped" or vice versa?

Comment: @hpy you should read the heatmap row-wise. The label suffixes `".pre"` and `".post"` on both axises also indicate the direction. So at the top right tile, 40% of those who chose "Fear of being wrong" also chose "Fear of being scooped".

Comment: @hpy In contrast, 10% of those who chose "Fear of being scooped" also chose "Fear of being wrong" (at the bottom left tile).

Comment: Understood. The code worked, thank you so much! It was not obvious to me at all that `full_join()` could be used for this purpose, and it still baffles me why sometimes you should use quotes for data frame variables (e.g. `by = "Response_ID"`) or not (e.g. `count(barriers.pre, barriers.post)`), but those are probably topics for another post. And thanks for giving a name to this ("association rules mining") along with the relevant package for advanced operations, and for the plot!!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over unique values of `barrier`; for each, filter the data to IDs endorsing that barrier, then calculate the conditional proportions.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # >= v1.0.0

props <- list_rbind(map(unique(dat$barriers), \(b) {
  dat %>%
    filter(b %in% barriers, .by = Response_ID) %>% 
    count(barrier1 = b, barrier2 = barriers, name = "prop") %>%
    mutate(prop = ifelse(
      barrier1 == barrier2,
      NA,
      prop / max(prop)
    ))
}))
```

```
# A tibble: 64 × 3
   barrier1                    barrier2                          prop
   <fct>                       <fct>                            <dbl>
 1 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Fear of being \"wrong\""        0.102
 2 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Don't expect useful feedback"   0.182
 3 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Don't know how to write it up"  0.262
 4 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Not how things are done"        0.299
 5 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Insufficient \"impact\""        0.294
 6 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "No benefit to career"           0.342
 7 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Don't know where to publish"    0.321
 8 "Fear of being \"scooped\"" "Fear of being \"scooped\""     NA    
 9 "Not how things are done"   "Fear of being \"wrong\""        0.104
10 "Not how things are done"   "Don't expect useful feedback"   0.252
# … with 54 more rows
```

And the heatmap:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(props, aes(barrier2, fct_rev(barrier1))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = prop), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = percent(prop, accuracy = 1)),
    size = 10 / .pt
  ) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", direction = 1) +
  labs(x = "Other Barriers Endorsed", y = "Barrier") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]